repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element
I have this error when deploy:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project workflow-impl: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :workflow-impl

the pom.xml:

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>workflow</groupId>
<artifactId>workflow</artifactId>
<version>2.5.8</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <activiti.version>6.0.0</activiti.version>
</properties>

<modules>
    <module>modules/java-workflow-api</module>
    <module>modules/java-workflow-impl</module>
</modules>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>sigit-releases</id>
        <name>SIGIT Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>https://sigit.com/nexus/content/repositories/uib/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>sigit-snapshots</id>
        <name>Project Snapshots Repository</name>
        <url>https://sigit.com/nexus/content/repositories/uib-snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>sigit-releases</id>
        <name>SIGIT Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>https:sigit.com/nexus/content/repositories/uib</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>sigit-snapshots</id>
        <name>Project Snapshots Repository</name>
        <url>https:sigit.com/nexus/content/repositories/uib-snapshots</url>
        <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>

and:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.15</version> <!-- Spring Boot Parent Version -->
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.workflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>workflow-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.8</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring.boot.version>2.5.15</spring.boot.version>
        <activiti.version>6.0.0</activiti.version>
        <ecas.version>4.62.0</ecas.version>
        <h2.version>1.4.200</h2.version>
        <junit.version>4.13.2</junit.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.26</lombok.version>
        <logback-classic.version>1.2.3</logback-classic.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.30</slf4j.version>
        <swagger-annotations.version>1.6.2</swagger-annotations.version>
        <tomcat.version>9.0.48</tomcat.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot Starter for JPA and H2 for Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot Starter for Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Activiti Workflow Engine Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
            <artifactId>activiti-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${activiti.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
            <artifactId>activiti-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${activiti.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Project API Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.workflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>workflow-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- H2 Database for Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>${h2.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback-classic.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ECAS Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.iam.ecas.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>ecas-tomcat-8.0</artifactId>
            <version>${ecas.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Unit Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Swagger Annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger-annotations.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Lombok for Code Generation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Tomcat (if needed) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>


"on project workflow-impl" - you need to check (or show us) another pom.xml

Did you get a chance to

check that the credentials you’re using to deploy have the necessary permissions to upload to the specified repository.
check for the correctness of server credentials in settings.xml under .m2\

    <servers>
      <server>
        <id>sigit-releases</id>
        <username>your-username</username>
        <password>your-password</password>
      </server>
      <server>
        <id>sigit-snapshots</id>
        <username>your-username</username>
        <password>your-password</password>
      </server>
    </servers>

